# Using a plus sign ( ) when passing a variable with a jquery object

Tags: jquery

I simply need an explanation as to why there needs to be a plus sign (+) before and after my defined variable when passing as an object -- just so I have a better understanding:

```
$('#mapForm').change(function() {   
var selectedState = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();    
$('a.dot[state*="'+selectedState+'"]').show(1000);
$('a.dot[state!="'+selectedState+'"]').hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: It's just string concatenation. The code inserts the value in the `selectedState` variable to the CSS selector.

Comment: Within Javascript, the + operator is responsible for string concatenation.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Comment: Please first read the docs for jquery and specially JS as JS is the language and then ask question here that is not subjective. As it isn't discussion board.It is Q&A board for questions having answer that is not subjective and community expect questions asked after a little bit more research, so this question isn't fit for this place.

Comment: @Hafiz: How is this subjective?

Comment: @BoltClock: Question itself isn't but asking about description and detail of concatenation is, see a comment below an answer. While there is lot of resources available that can be even found after simply google of very basic search. However, if you think that this question worth here then tell me too.

Comment: Still don't see how that is subjective.

Answer (score 2):

This "+" sign is used for concatenation here. So if you want to concatenate  you have to use this sign.

eg

```
     var r=5 
     console.log("value = "+r);
```

will log value = 5

In your case lets say value of selectedState if foo so:-

```
            $('a.dot[state*="'+selectedState+'"]').show(1000); becomes
            $('a.dot[state*="foo"]').show(1000);
```

Comment: +1 for the answer but add some more about concatenation! Questioner seems not be relevant with it :P

Comment: Thank you, what is throwing me off is why there needs to be a plus sign after the variable too.

Comment: well, @supamc99 that is due to because you have to specify the double/single quotes to be closed also. so, you have to add a plus sign to concatenate that double/single quote with your string! other wise , your function will not be executed. all the code after it will be considered as string in js :D for example:
`var s = "Heart";
$('"#"+s+"1"').show();` after execution it will become:
`var s = "Heart";
$('#Heart1').show();`